# Is it possible to add/multiply planes?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to add or multiply planes?

For example if I have $x+y+z=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, is it possible to do something like the following?
$${(x+y+z=0)+(x+y+z=0)}={(2x+2y+2z=0+0)}$$
$${(x+y+z=0)\cdot(x+y+z=0)}={(x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+xz+yz)=0\cdot0)}$$

Please excuse my (probably) dreadful notation - I wasn't sure how to represent this concept.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can do those operations. As you have already noticed, planes can be represented by equations and naturally, you can add or subtract or multiply the equations to each other.

For example, we can use addition/subtraction of two plane equations while finding the intersection of those planes (in this case, the planes are the same but assume planes are different).

Answer (score 3):

In the addition bit, you actually end up getting the same plane you had before: what you did was multiply your equation by two. You can actually "add" planes in a sense: given $\pi_1$, $\pi_2$ two affine planes, $\pi_1+\pi_2$ is defined as the smallest affine variety $Y$ so that $\pi_1,\pi_2\in Y$.

As for the multiplication part, that is perfectly correct in a geometric way: what you got by multiplying the two equations is the equation of a "double plane", which is a (degenerate) conic (a conic such as the ellipse, the parable...). If you are interested in the topic, you can research quite a lot about conics in any book about non-linear geometry, specially books about Projective Geometry.

Comment: Is the multiplication part like 'x+y=0' multiply by 'x-y=0' gives the 'stacking of both'?

Comment: Does this extend to exponentiation? If it's a conic, does that mean that planes do not have to be flat?

Comment: @KGSH If you multiplied 'x+y=0' and 'x-y=0', you would get the equation 'x^2-y^2=0'. This is not exactly the 'stacking of both': in this case, since the planes are different, you get the conic consisting of two intersecting planes (you can see it clearly if you plot the equation in some 3D software).

Comment: @DroidMonkey It does not extend to expoentiation beyond squares, since a conic must alwas have a grade 2 equation. And it is actually the other way around: planes have to be flat, but conics do not always have to be curved. If you leared the conics by the intersections of a plane and a cone, think about what you woud get if the plane went through the vertex of the cone: either one single point (the vertex) or two lines intersecting in the vertex. These are also conics (as are the planes here mentioned), they just have a different structure than the ones we are used to.

Comment: @ÁlvaroSerrano When you plot x^2-y^2=0 you get both of 'x+y=0' and 'x-y=0' on the same graph right? That's what i mean by stacking. Or maybe I should use 'compositing'?

Comment: @KGSHbteamMineTeamBeastO_ Yes, you are absolutely right. I'm sorry, Engilsh is not my first language and I didn't quite get what you meant. Keep in mind that it only Works with two planes, not more (you would get the equation right, but it would no longer be a conic).

Comment: Cool! It is not a problem.